# Creation of edaphology tag

Tags: discussion, support

I think questions about soil, as on-topic, should be taged with the Science that studies soil, Edaphology.

I would create it, but I cannot because it needs reputation.

Comment: I am going to ask the obvious question here, why are you going this if you do not have the repo to do it?

Comment: I am asking if it should be created @Gary Kindel. I cannot

Comment: You misunderstand my question.  If you did not have the rep to create the tag you should not be trying to create the tag.  Gain for rep and do this organically.  It is improper for a non-expert to manipulating the meta data.  Even if I have the rep to do it, I would NOT create tags outside my expertise.

Comment: @Gary Kindel. Edaphology is the science that study soils, I am not saying anything technical, just the tag is missing. btw 1,5k rep is needed. I would have that rep if I hadn't offer some bounties. I am on top 2% on 2019.

Comment: Why did you suicide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure! But "soil" should be a synonym. Or possibly the other way around.